# Using a List of Lists as parameters for changing letters in a string

Tags: python

I want to be able to take a string `string = Cookie` and replace specific letters with the parameters of a list of lists `list = [[C,3], [i,1]]`.
I know you can use `string.replace(C,3)` for example to replace just the C but I want it to go through the specified list and change any corresponding letters. I've tried changing the list to a string and using a for loop to iterate over list in string , but it does not work. Any suggestions?

this is what I have so far:

```
myString = "Mississippi"
pairsList = [['i', '1'], ['s', '$'], ['p', 'z']]

pairslist = ''.join(pairsList)

for i in myString:
    if pairslist in myString:
        newString = myString.replace[pairslist]
```

Comment: I suggest you show a [mre] of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: You also can't call .replace() with an integer argument (at least in the way you're describing).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `translate` method. For example,

```
mapping = str.maketrans({'C':'3','i':'1'})
print('Cookie'.translate(mapping))
```

The resulting output is `3ook1e`.

---

To match the example from the question:

```
myString = "Mississippi"
pairsList = [['i', '1'], ['s', '$'], ['p', 'z']]
mapping = str.maketrans(dict(pairsList))
print(myString.translate(mapping))
```

The result is `M1$$1$$1zz1`.

Answer (score 1):

IF you really wanted to do this with loops, you'd loop over the replacements:

```
myString = "Mississippi"
pairsList = [['i', '1'], ['s', '$'], ['p', 'z']]
for old,new in pairsList:
    myString = myString.replace(old,new)
```

But the `translate` solution is really the correct one here.